# motion effect to increase hight

Tags: jquery

Lets say that I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#changeText").click(function() {
$("#textBox").html("My<br><br><br>text<br><br><br>is<br><br><br>changed!");
});
});
```

The new text will make the #textBox div slightly taller.Is there any way to apply an effect to increase the height of the div slowly in a motion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.animate({height: +(your value)});` or `.height("yourvalue");`